# "New Console for notebook" for jupyter notebook in visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Jupyter lab has this feature where I can have a ipython console for every notebook I have opened. Whenever I run a cell inside this notebook, the console will have all the variables defined and modules imported corresponding to notebook. In addition, we can run extra commands and helps in debugging at times. **Is there a similar feature in VS code?** I really like it and would like to move completely to vs code. Python interactive command line in vscode is the closest to this that I found. However, it is not attached to the notebook and I have to run all the code inside the notebook which is a bit tedious.

Answer (score 8):

I believe this would work [Connecting a terminal to an existing kernel](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Connecting%20with%20the%20Qt%20Console.html)

However, you're likely looking for a way to do this within VS code. You might be able to do this by running `%connect_info` in a cell, starting a terminal, and then running the appropriate `jupyter` command.

Something like so:

```
jupyter console --existing kernel-2c0993da-95c7-435a-9140-118c10d33e1a.json
```

Comment: There is no supported 'window' for this at the moment. However we are working on support for connecting any notebook (or the interactive window) to an existing kernel.

Comment: You can track progress here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/6765

Comment: and here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/4573

Comment: While this is not as smooth as I would have liked, this is the best solution I found so far. Hopefully the developers will eventually add a feature to do basically this at the click of a button.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running version 1.84.2 of VS code, and here you can start a console session by running a notebook cell line by line. Once you run a cell line by line, a console session is automatically started in the Debug Console tab.

Running a cell line by line is done via a button above the cell:

[image]

Then you can access the console in the Debug Console tab:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're refering to .py files you can do that the same way you would in pycharm.
First, you need to put a breakpoint in the code:

[image: include in a break point]

Them you run the code with the debugger:
[image: debugger option]

Then, when the code reaches the breakpoint, you will be able to play with the variables, like the Jupyter terminal:

[image: debugger terminal]

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Overflow community, Walter. Thank you for making a contribution. I've moved your images inline so they're easier to view. But I think they'd be more useful if you cropped them a bit. As is, they have a lot of empty space, making it difficult to appreciate the salient details.

Comment: OP specifically asked about .ipynb files, not .py files.

Answer (score 1):

I also like to have a JupyterLab-style console open that is connected to a notebook. This is my workaround in order to achieve this in Visual Studio Code (at least it works when my kernel is a remote Jupyter session).

Suppose your notebook is called `hello.ipynb`.

1. Create a dummy file called `hello.py`.
2. Open `hello.py`, right-click in the code window and choose *Run Current File in Interactive Window*. This opens the JupyterLab-style console.
3. Change the kernel for the interactive window to the same kernel that the notebook `hello.ipynb` is using.
4. (Optional) Close the `hello.py` tab since it is not needed.

Now I have an interactive window sharing everything with the notebook.

Comment: Can you elaborate on Step 3? In the interactive tab, I can click on the current kernel in the top right, then click "Select another kernel...", then "Existing Jupyter Server..." and then an URL entry field appears. How do I find out what to enter there?

Comment: @Fritz Your Jupyter server IP/Hostname, which can be local (localhost) or remote (same LAN or not, e.g. 192.168.1.x ).

Comment: I can confirm this works as stated. However, if in the Notebook I select a line/group of lines and try to run them (Shift+Enter) it tries to run them on a terminal (not connected to the kernel). If I copy/paste those lines in this new "interactive session connected to the kernel" they run fine within the kernel, but copy/paste is tiring ...