# Python: Use Jupyter kernel in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, jupyter-notebook

I am using Python 3 in Visual Studio Code (latest version).

I am wondering if there is a way to run Python scripts (in .py format) in VSCode adopting Jupyter Notebook as default terminal (instead of Powershell).

In a few words, I would like to make VSCode similar to Spyder IDE, which uses Jupyter Notebook as terminal and shows script variables in Variables Explorer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Currently, VS Code does not support "Jupyter" as the default terminal when running Python code. If you want to use Jupyter, please create or open the ".ipynb" file in VS Code. In addition, you could try to use "[Interactive](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py)", which supports displaying the running results of python code and "Variables Explorer".

Answer (score 0):

Using [Jupyter extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter) you can create notebooks and interactive windows.

By clicking the Variables icon in the top toolbar after running code and cells, as mentioned on [vscode documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support#_variable-explorer-and-data-viewer), you can view your variable explorer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already know how to use Jupyter Notebooks in VSCode. What I am asking is a little bit different: I want to run a Python script (.py extension) in the Jupyter Kernel instead of the default powershell terminal. Thus, I will have almost the same experience as Spyder.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to run a Python script (.py extension) in the Jupyter Kernel instead of the default powershell terminal.

Option 1:

1. import the python Environment extension.
2. Run vs code from anaconda navigator.
3. the anaconda python environments should now be accessible from python Environment extension.

Option 2:

1. ctrl-shift-p
2. python: select interpreter
3. add interpreter

There are other options.

for .py files:

1. you can right click file or selected code
2. select "run in interactive window"

relevant links: [How do I find/excute Python Interactive Mode in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64730660/how-do-i-find-excute-python-interactive-mode-in-visual-studio-code)

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py

As for accessing the Jupiter kernel and the variables from the terminal. I would very much like to access them from the terminal too.

which is also discussed here:
["New Console for notebook" for jupyter notebook in visual studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58926229/new-console-for-notebook-for-jupyter-notebook-in-visual-studio-code) &
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/6765